# How to change values inside GLKMatrix4

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es

I want to know how to change the values inside GLKMatrix4.
I mean in static.

If any one knows explain me.If any tutorial to learn or to understand OpenGl reply me with the link... Except raywenderlich tutorial. Because i had already gone through it...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the headers?

```
#if defined(__STRICT_ANSI__)
struct _GLKMatrix4
{
    float m[16];
} __attribute__((aligned(16)));
typedef struct _GLKMatrix4 GLKMatrix4;    
#else
union _GLKMatrix4
{
    struct
    {
        float m00, m01, m02, m03;
        float m10, m11, m12, m13;
        float m20, m21, m22, m23;
        float m30, m31, m32, m33;
    };
    float m[16];
} __attribute__((aligned(16)));
typedef union _GLKMatrix4 GLKMatrix4;
#endif
```

It varies a bit based on your build environment and target platform/device, but long story short: all of the GLKit math types are plain-old-data structs (or unions), and you can access their members directly.